# .requestFocusInWindow() doesn't work when build the jar

Tags: java, swing, focus, executable-jar

I have a GUI Java application. The app minimizes to the system tray. I put a `frame.requestFocusInWindow()` for when the tray icon is clicked, so that the restored `JFrame` can gain the user attention.

The code as follow.

```
 trayicon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                if (e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1) frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.requestFocusInWindow();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TrayControl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
});
```

This works perfectly if I execute the app in NetBeans IDE, but when I build the .jar file and execute it, don't seems to work the `.requestFocusInWindow()` because the app window don't gain the user attention and is restored behind other windows that I had open. So what's happening here?

Comment: You could try wrapping the requestFocusInWindow method in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...). Or maybe try using the `grabFocus()` method on a component that has been added to the frame.

Comment: Thanks! But desn't work, the `JFrame` isn't show in front of others windows. I think that the problem isn't the focus, is the window state. The `JFrame` hides from the screen to a system tray icon when the minimized button is clicked, perhaps the problem is that when the tray icon is clicked, the `JFrame` is shown `frame.setVisible(true)` but is still minimized... Can be?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used `.setExtendedState()` metoth of the `JFrame` in the `MouseListener` as follow:

```
trayicon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TrayControl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
});
```